# Why was this question deleted?

Tags: discussion

My question was not extremely off topic nor rude, and thus, although I understand why it was closed, it should not have been deleted.

This was my question: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/40023/is-intelligent-design-unfalsifiable

Comment: There are at least two questions like that on philosophy.SE by the way.  https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/21569/why-arent-creationism-and-natural-science-on-the-same-intellectual-level?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/47360/how-is-intelligent-design-different-from-say-archeology I see you actually found the latter. Oddly I was not notified of Alex's answer there, under which I see you commented.

Answer (score 2):

It was completely off-topic, heavily down-voted and generated a lot of off topic comments. It also had a bad answer that needed to be deleted.

The system would eventually nuke it by itself, but we speeded that up because of the pointless moderation work it was generating.

Why would you want it undeleted? Do you have a proposal on how to salvage it?